# highcharts groups of stacked columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Starting from here http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/TfvGp/ I want to add some more data, which will be stacked on the columns as you can see in that example, on top of each 'Series' I want to add another set of data, so when you hover `Series 1` a label like:

```
 `Series 1 

  val1: val1, 

  val2: val2`
```

will be displayed.

```
series: [{name: "S1",
    data: [7,12,16,32,64]
},{ name: "S2",
    data: [7,12,16,32,64]
},{ name: "S3",
    data: [7,12,16,32,64]
}]
```

The data that I want to add it should be added on top of each series, and it must be related to each series so, if I want to hide `S1` the entire column should be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, to connect series use `linkedTo` for series. To set stacking, use `stacking:'normal'` and for series use `stack`. And here is a result: http://jsfiddle.net/TfvGp/50/

About tooltip, there's no simple solution for it. In Highcharts you can show or all series in tooltip, or just one. You can't choose two series for it. The best solution will be to loop over all series in `tooltip.formatter` and display series values only for the same stack as hovered point, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter). Happy coding ;)